# Each time a file is read, memory increases in .NET Core how to free up memory each time a file is read

Tags: c#

This is my code..

I want every call this method memory must not increase.
Thanks so much.

```
    public List<LogResult> GetData()
{
    var result = new List<LogResult>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("logs\\logsCopy.log"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                continue;

            var log = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogResult>(line.Remove(line.Length - 1, 1));

            result.Add(log);
        }

        if (result.Count > 0)
            return result.UnescapeMessage();
    }

    return new List<LogResult>();
}
```

Comment: Assuming all the rest is OK, it's a normal behavior: garbage collection should not start after each method call; garbage collector starts working (and freeing memory) when .Net wants to do it (garbage collection is time consuming: to save RAM bytes you should pay in CPU ticks). Technically, you can add `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);` but doubt you should do it.

Comment: How long have you been running this code? Do you experience problems with memory (i.e. OutOfMemoryException)? How this method is used? What is done with the result?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);` JIC the collections are big enough to hit LOH =)

Comment: Well, your approach is to read the entire file into memory, unless change your approach `List<LogResult>()` will remain in the memory no matter what you do. Instead you can return an `IEnumerable` that reads the file line by line when it is consumed.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You're already initializing a list, no point of initializing a new one if no log rows found, you can change `return new List<LogResult>();` at the end to `return result;`

Comment: You seem to be consuming some sort of LogFile. Maybe it would be beneficial to log to a database and work on that instead of a text file?

Comment: @Eldar How can i use IEnumerable ?

Comment: Enumerable: Have a look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield

Comment: @Eldar this Nlog files ..

Comment: @MilesMorales Is this called more than once per file? (or file version for that matter)

Comment: What is `return result.UnescapeMessage();` calling? I assume that `UnescapeMessage()` is some kind of extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` will look like the below :

```
public IEnumerable<LogResult> GetData()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("logs\\logsCopy.log"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                continue;

            var log = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogResult>(line.Remove(line.Length - 1, 1));
            // UnescapeMessage(log); 
           yield return log;
        }        
    }
}
```

This way `LogResult` objects will live separately in the memory and will allow  `GC` to collect them individually.

```
 var log = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogResult>(line.Remove(line.Length - 1, 1));
```

The above line may be changed into the below

```
 var log = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogResult>(line.AsSpan(0,log.Length-1));
```

It might be an overkill, and didn't test it but it may allocate one less string.

Comment: @Fildor failing to copy paste :)

Comment: This is not calling `UnescapeMessage()` like the original code does so the results are likely incorrect.

Comment: @MatthewWatson OP should rewrite that extension method to accept a `LogResult` instead of `List<LogResult>`,  good catch

Comment: A more idiomatic loop is `string line; while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {....`

Comment: Or `while (sr.ReadLine() is string line)` if you consider pattern matching idiomatic yet.